"'.../src/onnx/gen_proto.py' is not a Conan command" when building onnx
I have the following conanfile.py in my project on which I run the command conan install . --output-folder=build --build=missing -v.
import os

from conan import ConanFile

class ProjectRecipe(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    generators = "CMakeToolchain", "CMakeDeps"

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("armadillo/12.6.4")
        self.requires("openssl/3.3.1")
        self.requires("onnxruntime/1.18.1")
        self.requires("boost/1.86.0", force=True)


The command completes successfully. Below is the latter part of the output:
======== Installing packages ========
abseil/20240116.1: Already installed! (1 of 15)
bzip2/1.0.8: Already installed! (2 of 15)
cpuinfo/cci.20231129: Already installed! (3 of 15)
flatbuffers/23.5.26: Already installed! (4 of 15)
openblas/0.3.25: Already installed! (5 of 15)
zlib/1.3.1: Already installed! (6 of 15)
armadillo/12.6.4: Already installed! (7 of 15)
boost/1.86.0: Already installed! (8 of 15)
boost/1.86.0: Disabled magic autolinking (smart and magic decisions)
protobuf/3.21.12: Already installed! (9 of 15)
re2/20231101: Already installed! (10 of 15)
openssl/3.3.1: Already installed! (11 of 15)
onnx/1.16.2: Already installed! (12 of 15)
libcurl/8.10.1: Already installed! (13 of 15)
date/3.0.1: Already installed! (14 of 15)
onnxruntime/1.18.1: Already installed! (15 of 15)
WARN: deprecated: Usage of deprecated Conan 1.X features that will be removed in Conan 2.X:
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.names' used in: libcurl/8.10.1, flatbuffers/23.5.26, openblas/0.3.25, zlib/1.3.1, onnx/1.16.2, openssl/3.3.1, protobuf/3.21.12, abseil/20240116.1, boost/1.86.0, armadillo/12.6.4, bzip2/1.0.8
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.build_modules' used in: flatbuffers/23.5.26, onnx/1.16.2, openssl/3.3.1, protobuf/3.21.12, abseil/20240116.1, armadillo/12.6.4, bzip2/1.0.8
WARN: deprecated:     'env_info' used in: flatbuffers/23.5.26, openblas/0.3.25, openssl/3.3.1, protobuf/3.21.12, boost/1.86.0, bzip2/1.0.8
WARN: deprecated:     'cpp_info.filenames' used in: flatbuffers/23.5.26, protobuf/3.21.12, boost/1.86.0
WARN: deprecated:     'user_info' used in: boost/1.86.0

======== Finalizing install (deploy, generators) ========
conanfile.py: Writing generators to C:\Users\YawManu\source\repos\CMakeProject1\build
conanfile.py: Generator 'CMakeToolchain' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.py: CMakeToolchain generated: conan_toolchain.cmake
conanfile.py: CMakeToolchain: Preset 'conan-default' added to CMakePresets.json.
    (cmake>=3.23) cmake --preset conan-default
    (cmake<3.23) cmake <path> -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake  -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW
conanfile.py: CMakeToolchain generated: C:\Users\YawManu\source\repos\CMakeProject1\build\CMakePresets.json
conanfile.py: CMakeToolchain generated: C:\Users\YawManu\source\repos\CMakeProject1\CMakeUserPresets.json
conanfile.py: Generator 'CMakeDeps' calling 'generate()'
conanfile.py: CMakeDeps necessary find_package() and targets for your CMakeLists.txt
    find_package(Armadillo)
    find_package(onnxruntime)
    find_package(OpenSSL)
    find_package(Boost)
    target_link_libraries(... Armadillo::Armadillo onnxruntime::onnxruntime openssl::openssl boost::boost)
conanfile.py: Generating aggregated env files
conanfile.py: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat']
Install finished successfully

Yet the CMake generation in Visual Studio fails with the output (latter part):
1> [CMake] [DEBUG:VsDevCmd.bat] --------------------- VS Developer Command Prompt Environment [post-init] ---------------------
1> [CMake] [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
1> [CMake] [1/64] Running gen_proto.py on onnx/onnx.in.proto
1> [CMake] FAILED: onnx/onnx-ml.proto C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/b/onnxeaf435b38615b/b/build/Debug/onnx/onnx-ml.proto 
1> [CMake] C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\YawManu\.conan2\p\b\onnxeaf435b38615b\b\build\Debug && "C:\Program Files\Conan\conan\conan.exe" C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/b/onnxeaf435b38615b/b/src/onnx/gen_proto.py -p onnx -o C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/b/onnxeaf435b38615b/b/build/Debug/onnx onnx -m --protoc_path C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/proto8625022988b17/p/bin/protoc.exe"
1> [CMake] 'C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/b/onnxeaf435b38615b/b/src/onnx/gen_proto.py' is not a Conan command. See 'conan --help'.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] ERROR: Unknown command 'C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/b/onnxeaf435b38615b/b/src/onnx/gen_proto.py'
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] onnx/1.16.2: ERROR: 
1> [CMake] Package '6a7a6783386189c6725e6d4d255e7cdc4e450d20' build failed
1> [CMake] onnx/1.16.2: WARN: Build folder C:\Users\YawManu\.conan2\p\b\onnxeaf435b38615b\b\build\Debug
1> [CMake] ERROR: onnx/1.16.2: Error in build() method, line 136
1> [CMake]  cmake.build()
1> [CMake]  ConanException: Error 1 while executing
1> [CMake] CMake Error at cmake-conan/conan_provider.cmake:483 (message):
1> [CMake]   Conan install failed='1'
1> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
1> [CMake]   cmake-conan/conan_provider.cmake:591 (conan_install)
1> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:/Users/YawManu/source/repos/CMakeProject1/out/install/x64-debug"   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\YawManu\source\repos\CMakeProject1" 2>&1"' execution failed with error: ''C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' '/c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:/Users/YawManu/source/repos/CMakeProject1/out/install/x64-debug"   -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\YawManu\source\repos\CMakeProject1" 2>&1"' returned with exit code: 1'.


What could be wrong? Thank you in advance for helping.
EDIT: Below is the rule of the ninja file which causes the error.
#############################################
# Custom command for onnx\onnx-ml.proto

build onnx\onnx-ml.proto | ${cmake_ninja_workdir}onnx\onnx-ml.proto: CUSTOM_COMMAND C$:\Users\YawManu\.conan2\p\b\onnxeaf435b38615b\b\src\onnx\onnx.in.proto
  COMMAND = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\YawManu\.conan2\p\b\onnxeaf435b38615b\b\build\Debug && "C:\Program Files\Conan\conan\conan.exe" C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/b/onnxeaf435b38615b/b/src/onnx/gen_proto.py -p onnx -o C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/b/onnxeaf435b38615b/b/build/Debug/onnx onnx -m --protoc_path C:/Users/YawManu/.conan2/p/proto8625022988b17/p/bin/protoc.exe"
  DESC = Running gen_proto.py on onnx/onnx.in.proto
  restat = 1



The default build type for conan is Release, whereas your second snippet is (re)building everything in Debug mode. Try re-running your conan install command with -s build_type=Debug as extra flags. If that correctly builds, there is some kind of interaction between VS and conan.

The second snippet runs automatically when the CMake cache is being generated. Is there a way to change the command that is run?

It runs automatically because are building in Debug mode. See if you can fix the problem outside of VS first, because you have more control over  the CMake invocation that way.

Try first everything in the command line, to check if it works and remove moving parts. So after the conan install, some cmake --preset + cmake --build --preset should work.

I think I get your first comment now. Running with -s build_type=Debug now gives the same error as that of the CMake generation. What can I do to fix it?

Inspect the generated ninja file somewhere under onnxeaf435b38615b/b/build/Debug and find the rule that has "Running gen_proto.py on onnx/onnx.in.proto". Then edit your question with that rule and probably file a bug on Conan center.

According to the CMakeLists.txt file, conan.exe is being put in place of the variable PYTHON_EXECUTABLE. You should move one step up and figure out why that is happening.

Found it: it's part of the Conan recipe. And it is already reported as issue #22636 on the conancenter GitHub repo. It looks like #21790 has a comment with an answer. Suggest you read through both issues and consider whether you want to hack it now or submit a proper fix to conan.

The root cause is that the Conan recipe for onnx sets the PYTHON_EXECUTABLE variable to sys.executable. Normally this is the Python program used to invoke Conan, but in your case it is a conan.exe, which is not a Python interpreter.
This was reported upstream as issue #22636 and #21790.
The quick and dirty solution is to patch the conanfile.py of onnx, as stated in this comment:

After I modify conanfile.py using line tc.variables["PYTHON_EXECUTABLE"] = "python", it works now.

You will need a standalone Python installation for this to work, of course.

Will removing the conan installation done with the Windows installer and reinstalling from pip fix it more cleanly?

I have no idea :) It's worth a shot.
